# Email time format to logstash @timestamp

Tags: datetime, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to parse email date field to Logstash @timestamp field:

Example email date filed: `Mon, 28 May 2018 15:53:54 +0100`

Logstash config: `filter {date {match => ["date", "E, d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"]}`

Result @timestamp: `May 28th 2018, 14:53:54 +0000`

As you can see Logstash haven't added +0100.

Could you please tell me where I have done wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by result @timestamp ? if you mean kibana display this is normal as it converts the timezone for display. However you can specify a timezone in the settings

Comment: Hi Andrea, Yes, @timestamp is the field in Kibana. Mon, 28 May 2018 15:53:54 +0100 was the date filed in my email alert, but if I were to get an email in April it would be like: Mon, 20 Apr 2018 15:53:54 +0000, because of the daylight saving. Your suggestion did work. I haven't had the correct time zone in my computer. I don't see the option to mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: No problem happy to know that it worked now :)